# Sending a POST request with RestClient and Authentication headers

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I have the following curl request that I would like to translate into a RestClient API request.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Token user_token="tokenhere", email="email@myemail.com"' -X POST "https://api.myapi.io/reports?start_date=2016-05-10&end_date=2016-05-12" -v
```

I tried the following as a RestClient POST but I keep getting a 401. When I do the curl request I get a response.

```
url = "https://api.myapi.io/reports?start_date=2016-05-10&end_date=2016-05-12"

RestClient.post(url, :authorization => 'Token email="email@myemail.com" user_token="tokenhere"', :content_type => 'application/json', :accept => 'application/json')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `Authorization` header looks different (different order, missing comma). Maybe that's it?

Comment: Of course, your `url = ...` line is also missing a quote, so maybe these are just typos. :-)

Comment: @smarx is this what you mean? I tried this and it didn't work I got the same response: ```RestClient.post(url, :authorization => 'Token user_token="tokenhere", email="email@myemail.com"', :content_type => 'application/json', :accept => 'application/json')```

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. What's the body of the HTTP response? Does it give you a hint as to the issue?

Comment: That's not the body of the response. That's just the status.

Comment: RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: {"errors":null}. This is the only response that I get from the console.

Answer (score 1):

The string you're expecting is:

```
'Token user_token="tokenhere", email="email@myemail.com"'
```

The line you're sending is:

```
'Token email="email@myemail.com" user_token="tokenhere"'
```

The parameters are flipped around. :) If that doesn't work, I'd check and make sure that the curl request is expecting escaped characters. You could be effectively sending this:

```
"Token email=\"email@myemail.com\" user_token=\"tokenhere\""
```

Comment: How would I check if the request is expecting escaped characters?